# Many panels with buttons Play vidéos in c# with vlcPlugin

Tags: vlc

I want to Play an URL like this "http//:........" in my application with vlcPlugin (axVlc..21) , i use 3 or 4 user controls 'panels) with buttons to Play everyone a live channel, but when i use a panel and if i clik the buuton i have not the axVlc..21 , and i don't know how i déclare différent panels to Control vlcplayer!!

please help me ..
Greetings !

Comment: please do not use the axvlc code, it's not maintained at all

Comment: thank you mtz but what can i use instead please !!

Comment: for me i use vs 2019 windows 10 , i want just use player media to play the Url like m3u link , what s the best way to do that ? i wiat your answer , Thank you

Comment: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp